# why would a PHP Session Array not carry over to new page only on first instance on webserver, but works all the time on localhost

Tags: php, arrays, session, csv, export

I have a session multidimensional array that is being populated correctly labeled `$_SESSION['data']` that the user can export as a `.csv`. I have tested this on `localhost` and it works properly 100% of the time.

I have uploaded to webserver and it is no longer working properly
I have confirmed the array is being populated with real data by `print_r($_SESSION['data']);` and the results are displayed on the page with the data of interest every time. (i've currently disabled the output on the site itself to reduce the load time)

however the really weird thing that has been driving me nuts for a solid day now is it DOES work, but only after trying to export it once (which exports a blank file), run the page again and then hit export again (and it populates with the correct data)

here is the export code i am using

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$tdata = array();
$tdata = $_SESSION['data'];  

  function cleanData(&$str)
  {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
  }

  // file name for download
  $filename = "CSVOutput" . date('Ymd') . ".csv";
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

  $flag = false;
  foreach($tdata as $row) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      echo implode(",", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
      $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
    echo implode(",", array_values($row)) . "\n";
  }

  exit;

?>
```

and here is the link to my page that is misbehaving:

> http://mathdraft.com/FootballCalculator.php

after you open the page if you do the following you will create what i am experiencing

1. hit calculate
2. hit export
3. open up the csv - see that it is empty
4. hit calculate
5. hit export
6. open up the csv - it has the data

i have built this on `wamp` server using `php 5.5.12` my host has `php 5.3.29`

> http://mathdraft.com/phpinfo.php

is there some type of blatant error i am making in the above export code? or is it some server configuration? or is it (and i'm guessing it is this one) some function of my spaghetti code that is causing this error. it just baffles me that it would work half the time like this when the session array is being populated properly every time. it works 100% correct every time/calculation/iteration after this initial calculation

here is the `html` to call the `CSVout` procedure

```
<createcsv>
<FORM NAME ="form2" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "csvout.php">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit2" style="height:24px; width:145px; background-color:#FFFFCC; border-color: #556C55" VALUE = "Export Results">
</form>
</createcsv>
```

and the session creation `$_SESSION['data'] = $data;`

i'm really pulling my hair out on this one, any advice would be appreciated. this is my `PHP` learning project and i will be doing a redesign of the code but i just can't seem to let this minor bug go before starting it since this is the only thing that is holding me up from considering this version 1 "done"

Comment: I haven't been through all your code, but try adding `is_file()` to your download code, and if that returns false then the file isn't there. Then if trying to download the file again after a few seconds (as per your issue) then it's likely could this be a simple delay issue - i.e. too short a time between creating file and writing to disk, and download file.

Comment: if it is a delay issue would it be a good idea if i put a sleep(3); command to let it catch up a bit?

i can't test the is_file() at the moment. to clarify, downloading the file after a few second won't work - ive waited upwards of a minute to export while troubleshooting. however when recalculating and rexporting it will properly create the csv within a second each time

Comment: what if there are 100 additional people using the code, you'd need to change your code to sleep4? Nah. You need to create file, THEN allow download. Personally, I would have the "Calculate" button and script create calculations and CSV file as necessary, then once that script finishes (perhaps a header redirect) show the download button. If this is even your issue. Try this: do the calculate once (so you are at the point clicking export button gives an empty file) then go to your file directory where it *should* be and see if it is there. If not, click export again, then recheck the directory.

Comment: i think that is what i am doing (unless i am misunderstanding what you are saying). i have it so the numbers will crunch. the table will display (and the csv array is populated at that time the table is created) then when the table is done printing the button for the export comes up. i think the file is being created as when i hit the export button the browser will automatically download the csv so the file is there, it is just empty. as far as i know im not writing it to anywhere on the server and i'm not entirely sure where in the directory it should be based on code i posted. any ideas?

Comment: i believe i now understand what you mean. within my calculator php code i am now trying '$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

 foreach ($data as $fields) {
  fputcsv($fp, $fields);
 }

 fclose($fp);

        echo is_file('file.csv');'

and i am returning '1'. so i have the file! awesome. now how do i allow the user to retrieve it?

Comment: I've not done much with file write/open etc. So best rake through some tutorials/other Stack questions. I'd imagine if `is_file()` returns TRUE then show them download button, ELSE "Please wait a few seconds and refresh the page" or "click here"/whatever you want, then on refresh your code can check if is_file again, if TRUE show cvs dload button, if not TRUE it will display refresh message again.